# List Column Width won't change

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-view, content-editor-web-part

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have a list where I'm trying to enlarge the width of two particular columns.
Here's the JS that I'm attempting to put into use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 $("TH.ms-vh2:contains('Description')").css("width", "300px"); 
 $("TH.ms-vh2:contains('Analysis')").css("width", "200px"); 
 });
 </script>
```

However, the above code isn't having any effect when I use a Content Editor Web Part on the same page, and refer to this js file in the Site Assets folder.  The columns stay the same size.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: UPDATE:  I was actually able to make it work using a different approach to the code.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  I was actually able to make it work using a different approach to the code.

```
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='Description']
{
  width:250px;
}
```

...and so on. This seems to work properly.